# Label OR syntax

Tags: neo4j, cypher

What is the proper way of getting node labels with OR syntax?
For example:

```
CREATE (n:BMW:Bike {model:"C 600 Sport"});
CREATE (n:BMW:Car {model:"X3"});
CREATE (n:Honda:Bike {model:"Crossrunner"});
CREATE (n:Honda:Car {model:"Accord"});
```

Now, if we want to get all BMW Bikes (BMW AND Bike), then the following works:

```
MATCH n:BMW:Bike RETURN n;
```

But, if we want to get all Bikes OR Cars, what would be the proper syntax? The following does not seem to work:

```
MATCH n[:Bike|:Car] RETURN n;
```

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter on Labels. Below is what you need

```
START a=node(*) 
WHERE a:Bike OR a:Car 
RETURN a
```